# Work around Onesignal's Sanctions in an Ionic Application

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, onesignal

I created an app a while ago which used the Onesignal Push-Notification service for sending notifications.
Since I live in Iran and we are under several sanctions, the notification service doesn't work (and doesn't give me a player_id) unless the device is connected through a VPN.
I know there are alternatives to Onesignal but I suppose replacing them is gonna take a lot of time.
I may eventually give up and go after some alternatives but I want to absolutely make sure that I can't work around Onesignal's sanctions.
Since I'm new to Ionic, I wanted to ask if there's a way to set a proxy inside my application (that only affects my own app and doesn't "tunnel" the whole device). And if so, is it gonna make any difference in skipping the sanction?
Or are there any other work-arounds?
Or should I give up altogether?
I am willing to provide you with further information if needed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can try to help you with your problem:

- Use an **alternative** that *can also keep your OneSignal users* like Pushe (since you are in Iran and can't update the app)
  Simply go to the [website](https://pushe.co) and you can see the migrate button.
- Use services that **proxy OneSignal** (e.g. [YekSignal](https://yeksignal.com/))
- Since OneSignal SDK is open source you can **build one yourself** that uses your proxy VPN
  [This method](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/ed962e0b8b38c642a0fa9728dd30bc74edfabad6/OneSignalSDK/onesignal/src/main/java/com/onesignal/OneSignalRestClient.java#L89) seems to handle all the requests and you can proxy it and build it again.

Comment: Feel free to vote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Pushe doesn't support Android 7.0+ which is not a suitable option for me.
This is probably stupid but I cannot find the last file you linked (OneSignalRestClient.java) in my Ionic project so that I can change the BASE_URL.
Should I create a custom SDK on top of the original SDK and add my own changes to it?
If so, how can I add the custom SDK to my project?

Comment: @MiladFaint The link I provided refers to the Native SDK of OneSignal. To approach this goal you should change the native `AAR` and inject it to OneSignal Ionic SDK. As we know Ionic SDK uses native SDK (It's kind of a wrapper for native).

Comment: Also, Pushe supports Android 7+. What problem you're facing with about Pushe on API 24?

Comment: I've just noticed you are a Pushe dev. I had a conversation with one of your colleagues about a week ago and they've said it's not compatible with Android 7+ yet.

Comment: I've spoke with some of YekSignal's devs and they were very helpful. Managed to implement YekSignal on my project, Works like a charm!

Comment: Great. But I still haven't figured out what feature is not compatible with API 24+. Please explain more.